# Eigenvectors of the BCS Hamiltonian

Tags: superconductivity, eigenvalue

In introductory superconductivity one often studies the BCS Hamiltonian

$$H=
\begin{pmatrix} 
\xi & -\Delta \\
-\Delta & -\xi 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I can find the Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors by writing Eigensystem[H] in Mathematica.

I then obtain the eigenvalues
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&E_1 = \sqrt{\Delta^2 + \xi^2}\\
&E_2 = -\sqrt{\Delta^2 + \xi^2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
which I am happy with.

However, the Eigenvectors are given as
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&v_1 = \left\{-\frac{\xi + \sqrt{\Delta^2 + \xi^2}}{\Delta},1\right\},\\[1em]
&v_2 = \left\{\frac{-\xi + \sqrt{\Delta^2 + \xi^2}}{\Delta},1\right\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
which I am not happy with.

In the physics literature this is usually given as
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&v_1 = \{u,v\}\\
&v_2 = \{v,u\}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&u^2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 + \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{\xi^2 + \Delta^2}} \right)\\
&v^2 = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 - \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{\xi^2 + \Delta^2}} \right).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

My question is how can I get mathematica to give me the 'correct' eigenvectors.

I think the issue is two fold:

1. Mathematica does not care about the ratios $a/b$ and $c/d$ in $v_1 = \{a,b\}$ and $v_2 = \{c,d\}$
2. Mathematica does not understand that I'm looking for the eigenvectors that makes the matrix $P = \{v_1, v_2\}$ unitary

Comment: If I massage the results I find $v_2^{\mathrm{yours}} = \alpha \{v,u\}$ and $v_1^{\mathrm{yours}} = \beta \{v, - u\}$. For some real constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$. There is a minus sign that doesn't match up. Can you double check the result of the literature? I agree with the $v_{1,2}^{\mathrm{yours}}$.

Comment: As for point 1., Mathematica does care about the ratio, if the ratio was different they won't be eigenvectors. Rather it doesn't care about the ratio $a/c$.

Comment: How did you massage the expression to get $\alpha\{v,u\}$?

Comment: The notes I'm referring to is here on page 12: https://phy.ntnu.edu.tw/~changmc/Teach/SM/ch04.pdf

Comment: Correction, $v_1^{\mathrm{yours}} = \beta \{u,-v\}$, only the sign is wrong, not the order. Answering the question: a good old `FullSimplify` on Mathematica (taking the ratios that were supposed to be constant and assuming real coefficients etc...).

Comment: I hope its alright that I ask here, but I can't get that simplification. I get that the first number in $v_1^{yours}$ should be $u$, but for the second number I obtain a crazy expression that I can't seem to simplify to $v$.

Comment: Take $v_1^{\mathrm{yours}} / v_1$ term by term. Call it $\{x,y\}$. Full simplify $x/y$ assuming $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\Delta \in \mathbb{R}$. It should be something like $\pm \mathrm{sign}\,\Delta$.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get with my program

$$H=\left[ \begin {array}{cc} \xi&-\Delta\\-\Delta&-
\xi\end {array} \right] 
$$

Eigenvalues are:

$\lambda_1=\sqrt {{\xi}^{2}+{\Delta}^{2}}$

$\lambda_2=-\sqrt {{\xi}^{2}+{\Delta}^{2}}$

Eigenvectors (not normalized)

$$\vec{v}_1=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 1\\ {\frac {\xi-\sqrt {{
\xi}^{2}+{\Delta}^{2}}}{\Delta}}\end {array} \right] 
$$

$$\vec{v}_2=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 1\\ {\frac {\xi+\sqrt {{
\xi}^{2}+{\Delta}^{2}}}{\Delta}}\end {array} \right] 
$$

normalized eigenvectors :
$$ \vec{\hat{v}}_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\vec{v}_1\cdot \vec{v}_1}}\vec{v}_1$$

$$ \vec{\hat{v}}_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\vec{v}_2\cdot \vec{v}_2}}\vec{v}_2$$

so $ \vec{\hat{v}}_i\cdot  \vec{\hat{v}}_i=1$ and $ \vec{\hat{v}}_i\cdot  \vec{\hat{v}}_j=0$

Comment: Okay, but how are these vectors related to the ones in the literature? (See question above)

Comment: this I can't tell you . is your $v_1$ and $v_2$ correct ?. they are not normalized ?

Comment: They are normalized because $u^2 + v^2 = 1$.

Comment: I think that the calculation of the eigenvectors is not unique?

Comment: For a general matrix, I agree. But I think the fact that the opetators should anti-commute should give unique eigenvectors somehow. That is after all what follows when performing a bogoliubov transformation on the Hamiltonian